# How to open RDLC report without converting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, rdlc, rdl

Good day,

I was developing in Visual Studio 2015 and created RDLC reports for our project. After installing Visual Studio 2019 and trying to edit the report, I get a message to convert my reports to the latest RDLC format.
[Conversion Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjnx3.png)
If I do decide to convert it I get an error on this line of code:

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(rParams);
```

I was able to convert the report back to the previous version, but I want to know how can I edit the my reports without converting it?

If I'm not able to edit the report without conversion, then how do I solve the error I get when I SetParameters?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See following : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001&force_isolation=true

Comment: Please also post the error message.